# Twitter4j streaming api: getRetweetCount returns 0

Tags: twitter, streaming, twitter4j

I am using twitter streaming API with twitter4j (twitter4j-stream-3.0.3.jar) and getting retweet count using **getRetweetCount**. But it always returns 0.

Anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use status.getRetweetedStatus().getRetweetCount()

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent error you should check null before assign it to a value:

```
val retweetCount = if (tweet.getRetweetedStatus != null) tweet.getRetweetedStatus.getRetweetCount else 0
```